# How to see the projects we trust in Alexandria?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

In Alexandria, when I try to compile a project that have build events, I receive this warning

[image]

How can I see the list of the project that I have already trusted with "Always trust this project"? where this info is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored in the registry in a value keyed by the ProjectGuid from the .proj file with the project name as the data value.

```
HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Compiling\TrustedBuildEvents
```

Not sure how secure this is since a 'bad project' could put a GUID that might already be trusted in the .proj file. The project name also needs to match so probably not that much of an issue.

[image: Registry editor with the key selected]

Used SysInternals [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to capture events to see what BDS.exe was doing after always trust was selected and then yes clicked.

Answer (score 1):

These projects are stored in the Delphi registry under *Compiling\TrustedBuildEvents*.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to provoke the IDE to show that dialog? I just tried to add a pre build event to a test project, closed and reopened it and compiled it without getting that message.

Comment: @dummzeuch: With which Delphi version did you try?

Comment: Delphi 11.2 Alexandria

Comment: @dummzeuch could you try in android ? it's where me I have the popup

Comment: It works with a simple VCL project without closing/reopening. Must be something else prohibiting it. Try to remove any non standard addon.

Comment: To test I just put `dir` in the commands property of the post built event for a new project. The project properties dialog comes up with the current target selected so no other changes needed. The dialog comes up when you run/build even if not yet saved.